# X11: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key

Tags: x11, xorg

I have a headless (no monitor at all) test rig for crypto mining with two graphic cards on it.  It worked fine until update to release 17.10.

cuda-9-0.176-1 and nvidia-384.90-0ubuntu3.17.10.1 packages are installed

Here is some more info:

```
ghopper@miner:~$ uname -a 
Linux miner 4.13.0-17-generic #20-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 6 10:04:08 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

ghopper@miner:~$ env
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln... bla-bla-bla
LC_MEASUREMENT=ru_RU.UTF-8
SSH_CONNECTION=10.10.1.67 48684 10.10.1.64 22
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
LC_PAPER=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
DISPLAY=:0
LC_NAME=ru_RU.UTF-8
XDG_SESSION_ID=7
USER=ghopper
PWD=/home/ghopper
HOME=/home/ghopper
SSH_CLIENT=10.10.1.67 48684 22
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
LC_ADDRESS=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=ru_RU.UTF-8
SSH_TTY=/dev/pts/0
MAIL=/var/mail/ghopper
TERM=xterm-256color
SHELL=/bin/bash
SHLVL=1
LC_TELEPHONE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LOGNAME=ghopper
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
PATH=/home/ghopper/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:...
LC_IDENTIFICATION=ru_RU.UTF-8
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LC_TIME=ru_RU.UTF-8
_=/usr/bin/env

ghopper@miner:~$ cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 384.90  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-05)  Tue Sep 19 18:13:03 PDT 2017

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060 3GB"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1060 3GB"
    BusID          "PCI:3:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP-0"
    Option         "Coolbits" "31"
    Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP-0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "True"
    Option         "UseDisplayDevice" "DFP-0"
    Option         "Coolbits" "31"
    Option         "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP-0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And the problem itself (through ssh):

```
ghopper@miner:~$ nvidia-settings 
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.

ghopper@miner:~$ DISPLAY=:0 nvidia-settings 
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.

ghopper@miner:~$ DISPLAY=:1 nvidia-settings 
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
ERROR: The control display is undefined; please run `nvidia-settings --help` for usage information.
```

What should I do to solve the issue?

Comment: `ghopper@miner:~$ xauth list` ->

`miner/unix:0  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  2386b22487fb3507bdb0a62d36c2da20`